# Appending to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, arrays, stream

I'm trying to append some data to a stream.  This works well with `FileStream`, but not for `MemoryStream` due to the fixed buffer size.

The method which writes data to the stream is separated from the method which creates the stream (I've simplified it greatly in the below example).  The method which creates the stream is unaware of the length of data to be written to the stream.

```
public void Foo(){
    byte[] existingData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foo");
    Stream s1 = new FileStream("someFile.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
    s1.Write(existingData, 0, existingData.Length);


    Stream s2 = new MemoryStream(existingData, 0, existingData.Length, true);
    s2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End); //move to end of the stream for appending

    WriteUnknownDataToStream(s1);
    WriteUnknownDataToStream(s2); // NotSupportedException is thrown as the MemoryStream is not expandable
}

public static void WriteUnknownDataToStream(Stream s)
{
   // this is some example data for this SO query - the real data is generated elsewhere and is of a variable, and often large, size.
   byte[] newBytesToWrite = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("bar"); // the length of this is not known before the stream is created.
   s.Write(newBytesToWrite, 0, newBytesToWrite.Length);
}
```

An idea I had was to send an expandable `MemoryStream` to the function, then append the returned data to the existing data.

```
public void ModifiedFoo()
{
   byte[] existingData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foo");
   Stream s2 = new MemoryStream(); // expandable capacity memory stream

   WriteUnknownDataToStream(s2);

   // append the data which has been written into s2 to the existingData
   byte[] buffer = new byte[existingData.Length + s2.Length];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(existingData, 0, buffer, 0, existingData.Length);
   Stream merger = new MemoryStream(buffer, true);
   merger.Seek(existingData.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   s2.CopyTo(merger);
}
```

Any better (more efficient) solutions?

Comment: Can you please explain why you are not using an expandable stream for both writes?

Comment: ah, like so?  Stream s2 = new MemoryStream(); // expandable capacity memory stream
            
            s2.Write(existingData, 0, existingData.Length);
            
            WriteUnknownDataToStream(s2);

Comment: Yes that is what I mean... that's why it's a stream and not an array, no?

Comment: @Rotem @ sprocketonline One of you should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: Just create a `MemoryStream`, append the `existingData` to that stream, the continue appending data to it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A possible solution is not to limit the capacity of the `MemoryStream` in the first place.
If you do not know in advance the total number of bytes you will need to write, create a `MemoryStream` with unspecified capacity and use it for both writes.

```
byte[] existingData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foo");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(existingData, 0, existingData.Length); 
WriteUnknownData(ms);
```

This will no doubt be less performant than initializing a `MemoryStream` from a `byte[]`, but if you need to continue writing to the stream I believe it is your only option.

Comment: If the performance difference is important, you can [specify initial capacity of the stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx3c0489.aspx). This way, if you guess well (or know) the final size, there will be no reallocations. If you guess badly, you will waste memory or have reallocations that affect performance, but it will still work.