# Reading a MemoryStream containing opus audio with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to play opus audio files from web which I try to buffer with a `MemoryStream`. I'm aware of NAudio's ability to take urls however I need to set cookies and user agent before I access the file so this eliminates that option.
My latest approach was to buffer 30~ seconds of stream, feed it to `StreamMediaFoundationReader` and write to the same `MemoryStream` when needed, however NAudio ends up playing the initial buffered segment and stop after that is completed. What would be the correct approach for this?

Here's my current code if needed. (I have no idea how audio streaming works so please go easy on me)

```
bufstr.setReadStream(httpreq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()); //bufstr is a custom class which creates a memorystream I can write to.
StreamMediaFoundationReader streamread = new StreamMediaFoundationReader(bufstr.getStream());
bufstr.readToStream(); //get the initial 30~ seconds of content
waveOut.Init(streamread);
waveOut.Play();
int seconds = 0;
while(waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing) {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    seconds++;
    if (secs % 30 > 15) bufstr.readToStream();
}
```

bufstr's readToStream method

```
public void readToStream() {
    int prevbufcount = totalbuffered; //I keep track of how many bytes I fetched from remote url.
    while (stream.CanRead && prevbufcount + (30 * (this.bitrate / 8)) > totalbuffered && totalbuffered != contentlength) { //read around 30 seconds of content;
                Console.Write($"Caching {prevbufcount + (30 * (this.bitrate / 8))}/{totalbuffered}\r");
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                bufferedcount = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                totalbuffered += bufferedcount;
                memorystream.Write(buf, 0, bufferedcount);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339903).

Comment: I originally set the capacity of MemoryStream based on the content length response I get from server, however not setting memorystream's length didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging I found out that content length I get from server does not match with the actual size of stream, so I ended up calculating content length via other details I get from server.
The issue might also be a race condition due to the fact that it stopped after I manually kept track of where I write on memory stream